# how to import values json file into index file in NEXT13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am facing challenges importing a json file from the root directrory of my Next project. i keep getting no such file or directory

i tried using the import products from '@/....' . Also tried using useState and useEffect. still faced this error even though the file is in the root directory

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mac/development/Next/pre-render/pre-render1/data/backend.json'] {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'open',
path: '/Users/mac/development/Next/pre-render/pre-render1/data/backend.json',
page: '/'
}